# Trying to push to github reverted hours of progress

Tags: java, git, github

I am making a Minecraft mod with java and recently, Minecraft had a new update, so I had to update my mod accordingly.
I started from scratch making a new mod folder, and copied and fixed everything. Now that I have everything working, I thought I'd push my new mod to a new branch in my github repository.
I Initialized git in my VScode project, and I committed all changes.
Then added my github repository and tried to push to main.
I checked github and there were no changes. I looked back to my project and realized that *my files were replaced with the old files from my github repo.*
I did not pull, or try to merge, I just tried to push my files to my repository, and that caused days of work to be deleted from my PC.

Now, Why did this happen, How can I avoid it in the future, and is there anyway to revert what github did?

Comment: Do you see your "lost" commit in `git log --all` or `git reflog`?

Comment: If you run `git push` *without* `--force` or similar, you should never lose any commits. You may have some trouble *finding* the commits (how do you find one specific pine tree for your Christmas tree, when you go out to a forest or lot full of pine trees all of which *could be* your Christmas tree? They all look alike! Which one will you choose? How?) but they should all be *there*.

Comment: Meanwhile, some set of exact command line commands that produce the error (i.e., a [mre]) would help people figure out where things went wrong. I realize this may be very hard to come by for something like what you've just described.

Comment: "How to avoid it in the future" - don't make a copy, clone the repository, possibly make a new branch, commit often and push (to your work branch) at least daily. Then you will never lose much work. As for finding the files, what does "git branch -a" tell you?

Comment: @Jay Nope. I don't see any of the lost commits there.
@ torek I know, I searched everywhere but couldn't find anything.
@ ewramner "git branch -a" gives me 2 local branches, main and master, and the 3 remote branches i have.
I suspect my commit got pushed to another branch or there was some confusion between the two. I will try to search through them now.

Comment: @ewramner Hey man. It seems that "master" branch was created and my files were pushed to it. I have fixed everything and you have saved me hours of work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, There was a hidden local branch that didn't want to show up. If you have this issue try `git branch -a` or try checking your IDE's timeline (if you have that.)